# Can't Set Background on MasterPage

Tags: asp.net, css, background

I need to set a background for my website so that each web form child of the master page would show the background image.
I've googled it and found a few answers but they didn't do anything.
I am attaching my Master Page html code and an image showing the background I want:

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="Pages_MasterPage" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Qwik ProjecTrace</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .style2
        {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 40pt;
            color: #0066CC;
        }
        .style3
        {
            font-size: x-large;
        }



        body
        {
            background:url('/style/images/IMS-Backgroung.jpg') no-repeat left top;
        }





</style>
    <link href="../Style/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

    <table class="style1">
        <tr>
            <td runat="server" style="direction: ltr">
                <asp:Image ID="mes1" runat="server" style="text-align: left" />
            </td>
            <td class="style2">
                <strong style="font-size: 40">Qwik ProjecTrace<br />
                <span class="style3">you see what we do 24/7</span></strong></td>
            <td runat="server" style="direction: rtl">
                <asp:Image ID="mes2" runat="server" style="text-align: right" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

            <p></p>

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Here's the path to the background image:]

Does anyone know what is wrong with my code ? And how to set that background?

Thanks ahead

Comment: Your body css class is valid. Site.css might be overwriting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code solution (It seems that in my case, I had some kind of a problem with the containing folders):

```
body
    {
        background-image: url('../style/images/Background.jpg'); 
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change body style like this:

```
body
{
    background-image: url('/style/images/IMS-Backgroung.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Make sure that page from where your are accesing is "sitting" in parent folder of "/style/images/".

I would advice you to use asp.net themes where you can point to image like this: background-image: url('IMS-Backgroung.jpg') and will work for entire web app structure.

More about Themes can be found on [ASP.NET Themes and Skins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: My master page is "sitting" in the "Pages" directory, and the background is in /style/images.
I tried to change my code according to your advice but it still doesn't show the background when I load one of the child forms.

Comment: Is this child form in the same directory as master page or in subfolder?

Comment: Well yes indeed. You can see it clearly in the image I've added: look into the "Pages" directory - there you'll find the master page & login page and more.

Comment: Check for any body css declaration in your project that might override style above, clear browser cached files and restart the app. This should work, I have setup similar scenario and style was applied successfully.

Comment: I've restarted the application and it didn't help. 
Moreover, I've tried this solution on another project that contains a master page and a child web form and it worked.
I didnt know what else to do so this is what I did:
`.bodyCss
{
  background-image: url('/style/images/yellowBck.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;   
}`

and added:
`<body class="bodyCss">
......
</body>`

and it still didnt work.